# React - When search (filter) cannot find it is stuck

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs

From my latest React Search (filter) implementation which I have many people help me until it is success.
I have another issue that when the search (filter) cannot find any data in the content, it is stuck then I have to enter from the input box to initial search again.

The following attached image show that I search 111, if I delete it to 11 it is still working fine, but if I search 11111 it show nothing and after delete 11111 to 111 it still show nothing so I have to enter to start new search.
[image]

Issue image (after delete search value, nothing show)
[image]

The search (filter) code:

```
filterList = (e) => {
    let { value } = e.target
    this.setState({ value }, () => {
        var searchValue = this.state.value.toLowerCase();
        var updatedList = this.state.holder;
        updatedList = updatedList.filter((item) => {
            return Object.keys(item).some(key => item[key].toString().toLowerCase().search(searchValue) !== -1);
        });
        this.setState({ issues: updatedList });
    });
  }
```

After debugging from console I found that

- this.state.holder (original temp is ok)
- this.state.issues (filtered content is ok)
- But this.state.pageOfItems (after it is empty, then nothing show)

Could anybody please help to check my code?

Note: I use the pagination from http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/03/14/react-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google

IssueList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import Pagination from '../components/Pagination';
import IssueAdd from '../components/IssueAdd';

class IssueList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        issues: [],
        holder: [],
        pageOfItems: [],
    };


    this.createIssue = this.createIssue.bind(this);
    this.onChangePage = this.onChangePage.bind(this);
    this.filterList = this.filterList.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  //componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  //    this.loadData();
  //}
  // Load all new database after changed

  loadData() {
    fetch('/api/issues').then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        response.json().then(data => {
          data.records.forEach(issue => {
            issue.created = new Date(issue.created);
            if (issue.completionDate) {
              issue.completionDate = new Date(issue.completionDate);
            }
          });
          this.setState({ issues: data.records, holder: data.records });
        });
      } else {
        response.json().then(error => {
          alert(`Failed to fetch issues ${error.message}`);
        });
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      alert(`Error in fetching data from server: ${err}`);
    });
  }

  createIssue(newIssue) {
    fetch('/api/issues', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(newIssue),
    }).then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        response.json().then(updatedIssue => {
          updatedIssue.created = new Date(updatedIssue.created);
          if (updatedIssue.completionDate) {
            updatedIssue.completionDate = new Date(updatedIssue.completionDate);
          }
          const newIssues = this.state.issues.concat(updatedIssue);
          this.setState({ issues: newIssues });
        });
      } else {
        response.json().then(error => {
          alert(`Failed to add issue: ${error.message}`);
        });
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      alert(`Error in sending data to server: ${err.message}`);
    });
  }

  onChangePage(pageOfItems) {
    this.setState({ pageOfItems: pageOfItems });
  }

  filterList = (e) => {
    let { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ value }, () => {
        var searchValue = this.state.value.toLowerCase();
        var updatedList = this.state.holder;
        updatedList = updatedList.filter((item) => {
            return Object.keys(item).some(key => item[key].toString().toLowerCase().search(searchValue) !== -1);
        });
        this.setState({ issues: updatedList });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Issue Tracker</h1>
        <hr />
        <div className="filter-list">
            <form>
                <fieldset className="form-group">
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        className="form-control form-control-lg" 
                        placeholder="Search" 
                        onChange={this.filterList}
                    />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div className="panel panel-default">
                <table className="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Owner</th>
                    <th>Created</th>
                    <th>Effort</th>
                    <th>Completion Date</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {this.state.pageOfItems.map(issue => (
                        <tr key={issue._id}>
                                <td>{issue._id}</td>
                                <td>{issue.status}</td>
                                <td>{issue.owner}</td>
                                <td>{issue.created.toDateString()}</td>
                                <td>{issue.effort}</td>
                                <td>{issue.completionDate ? issue.completionDate.toDateString() : ''}</td>
                                <td>{issue.title}</td>
                              </tr>
                            ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        <Pagination
            items={this.state.issues}
            onChangePage={this.onChangePage}
        />
        <hr />
        <IssueAdd createIssue={this.createIssue} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default IssueList;
```

Comment: Are you reverting the results list back to it's original, unfiltered state when you clear the filter? i'm wondering if you may be trying to filter against an empty list.

Comment: Probably @JustinPearce is right, you are filtering the mutated list for the records and not all the available data records.

Comment: Hi Justin, I use the temp this.state.holder as the original. Every time I change the value in the input text box it should search from this.state.holder, so how can I clear the filter as you mention?

Comment: Hi @Justin Pearce, Thanks for your help. I get it, the pagination query from issues not from holder. Anyway, I'm curious how can I reset that empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Justin Pearce and @Tomas Eglinskas.

Finally, I found that I have to comment out the condition in the pagination (setPage function).

```
setPage(page) {
        var { items, pageSize } = this.props;
        var pager = this.state.pager;

        //if (page < 1 || page > pager.totalPages) {
        //  return;
        //}

        pager = this.getPager(items.length, page, pageSize);
        var pageOfItems = items.slice(pager.startIndex, pager.endIndex + 1);
        this.setState({ pager: pager });
        this.props.onChangePage(pageOfItems);
    }
```

I don't know that in the future, one day I will get the error???